# Component inside component not refreshing view on simple changes

Tags: angular

Given this parent component:

```
<div class="grid-row" *ngFor="let row of (grid$ | async); let rowIndex = index">
    <div (click)="createNote(rowIndex, columnIndex)" class="grid-column" *ngFor="let column of row; let columnIndex = index">
        <app-note [title]="column.title" [content]="column.content" *ngIf="column"></app-note>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this child component (app-note):

```
<div class="note">
    <div (click)="editTitle(true)" class="header">
        <span [class.hidden]="titleEditable">{{title}}</span>
        <input [class.hidden]="!titleEditable" [value]="title" />
    </div>
    <div (click)="editContent(true)" class="body">
        <span *ngIf="!contentEditable">{{content}}</span>
        <input *ngIf="contentEditable" (onBlur)="editContent(false)" [value]="content" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Which has this component logic:

```
export class NoteComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: string = "";
  @Input() content: string = "";

  titleEditable: boolean = false;
  contentEditable: boolean = false;

  constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  editTitle(edit: boolean) {
    this.titleEditable = edit;
  }

  editContent(edit: boolean) {
    this.contentEditable = edit;
    console.log("editContent", this.contentEditable);
  }

}
```

Whenever I execute the edit functions, the view is not updating while the value changes. This is probably related to some type of change detection that is not triggering. The thing is that this is just the child component logic, not bound to any parent property, so nothing is really changing between the parent and the child, just the child view itself.

Already tried to call `.detectChanges()` and other `ChangeDetectorRef` methods but without luck.

Why does this happen?
If I move this child component to the same level as the parent it is working as it should.

Comment: It looks like this should work.. however, the issue might be in the parent? Any onPush used there?

Comment: @MikeOne there's no onPush strategy on the parent...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the primitive booleans aren’t detected in your specific setup (not sure why). You could try to change the bools to objects like {value: true} and change them by returning a new object every time. maybe it helps?